# Firebase Cloud Messaging - Error calling firebase.messaging()

Tags: javascript, django, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting an error when calling `firebase.messaging()` from the html page (not the service worker) that makes no sense.

> Messaging: Please ensure that 'messagingSenderId' is set correctly in
>   the options passed into firebase.initializeApp().
>   (messaging/bad-sender-id).

The app IS initialized with the correct `messagingSenderId` in a `<script>` further up in the `<head>`.  The default app is shown in the console log:

```
function deviceRegistration() {
    console.log('in deviceRegistration()');
    console.log("firebase.apps:", firebase.apps);
    console.log("firebase.apps.length: ", firebase.apps.length);
    if (firebase.apps.length == 0) {
        // firebase.initializeApp({{ fcm_config.messagingSenderId }});
        firebase.initializeApp({"messagingSenderId": "1234567890"});
    }
    console.log("after initializeApp");  // prints to console
    var messaging = firebase.messaging();  // error happens here
    console.log("after firebase.messaging()");  // doesn't print to console
```

The reason I only call `firebase.initializeApp` if there are no apps in `firebase.apps` is because when I call `firebase.initializeApp` without first performing this check I get the following error:

> Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists
>   (app/duplicate-app).

I thought I'm supposed to be able to call `initializeApp` repeatedly (on every page) and it would register the service worker if necessary...

Can someone please help me figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh silly me...

I populated the config variable with a (django) template tag and context variable that I incorrectly referenced. I did this:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "{{ fcm_config.apiKey }}",
    authDomain: "{{ fcm_config.authDomain }}",
    databaseURL: "{{ fcm_config.databaseURL }}",
    projectId: "{{ fcm_config.projectId }}",
    storageBucket: "{{ fcm_config.storageBucket }}",
    messagingSenderId: "{{ fcm_config.messagingSenderId }}"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

When I meant to do this:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "{{ fcm_config.config.apiKey }}",
    authDomain: "{{ fcm_config.config.authDomain }}",
    databaseURL: "{{ fcm_config.config.databaseURL }}",
    projectId: "{{ fcm_config.config.projectId }}",
    storageBucket: "{{ fcm_config.config.storageBucket }}",
    messagingSenderId: "{{ fcm_config.config.messagingSenderId }}"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

So firebase was right to complain about a bad sender ID, since I was passing in an object equivalent to:

```
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
});
```

Now that part works and I'm on to the next error!

(if you're wondering why I put those variables in `fcm_config.config.*`, which seems redundantly redundant, it's because I also store `fcm_config.VAPID`)

Comment: This answer helped me realize I was setting `messagingSenderId` as an integer value, when it needed to be set as a string value. As soon as I changed it to a string instead of an int, the error went away. Doh!